# T_Latency = T_Propagation + T_Transmit + T_Queue?

Tags: layer1, bandwidth, latency

I am currently learning about the so-called 'physical layer' of a computer network. The following claim is made:

> The *latency of a message* is the *total time* for the whole message to arrive:
> T_Latency = T_Propagation + T_Transmit + T_Queue
> T_Propagation = distance / speed-of-propagation-in-medium
> T_Transmit = message-size / bandwidth
> T_Queue = time-spent-in-all-the-queues-in-the-path

I tried thinking about this from a physics standpoint (since this is the 'physical layer'), and I don't understand why this would be an additive relationship. It makes sense that T_Latency would *depend* on things like the speed of propagation in the medium, the bandwidth of the medium, and the time spent in queue, but why would it be equal to the sum of all of these? What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: The queueing delay doesn't belong to the physical layer, it's L2 or higher.

Comment: @Zac67 Hmm, maybe. So you're saying that T_Transmit should actually be 'serialization delay'? And so then we have T_Latency = T_Propagation + T_Serial?

Comment: "Transmission delay" is ambiguous, "serialization delay" isn't. Yes, the data needs to be serialized and the transmitted of the medium (propagation delay). The deserialization overlaps with the previous steps, so you don't count it. The sum of T_ser + T_prop is your physical-layer delay or latency.

Comment: @Zac67 Ok, I guess that clarifies things. Thanks for the help!